# Bootstrap form group not aligning correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code I am referring too: http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9ne/1/

If you expand the output window so they are not stacked, you can see that the column on the right is slightly messed up. The left and right have identical code and an identical column span.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="page-header">
            <h3>Your Profile</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">               <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">email@email.com</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">01258989</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender" class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Gender:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <input class="form-control input-block" name="gender" type="text">                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Player Type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form></div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">email@email.com</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">01258989</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender" class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Gender:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="gender" type="text">                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Player Type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this HTML - http://jsfiddle.net/Rn9ne/3/

You need to add the class "form-horizontal" on the right block.

```
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Your Profile</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">               <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                    <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                    <p class="form-control-static">email@email.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Phone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                    <p class="form-control-static">01258989</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender" class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Gender:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                    <input class="form-control input-block" name="gender" type="text">                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Player Type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                    <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                    <p class="form-control-static">email@email.com</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Phone</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                    <p class="form-control-static">01258989</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="gender" class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Gender:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                    <input class="form-control input-sm" name="gender" type="text">                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Player Type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-9"><input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Save"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe "form-group" class works within FORM tags. Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="page-header">
                <h3>Your Profile</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form method="POST" action="" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">               
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">email@email.com</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">01258989</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender" class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Gender:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <input class="form-control input-block" name="gender" type="text">                      </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Player Type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">email@email.com</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Phone</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">01258989</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender" class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Gender:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <input class="form-control input-sm" name="gender" type="text">                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-sm-4 control-label col-sm-pad">Player Type</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pad">
                        <p class="form-control-static">Jon</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Save">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stevenng/Rn9ne/4/

Comment: The fiddle is more or less the same as the original one. Its still broken.